# Probability on cards and bullet hitting target.

Tags: probability

> (i)  The probability of piercing target by a bullet is $\frac{1}{4} $ . Then if $20$ bullets are fired simultaneously , then what is the probability of getting the target?
>
> (ii)  What is the probability of not getting king of same colours when $2$ cards are drawn from $52$ with replacement  ?

**MY WORK:** 
For (i)  , I say that   if none of the bullets hit the target,  then the probability is :
$$\frac{3^{20}}{4^{20}}$$

Then, probability  that  one or more bullet hits target :
$$1-\frac{3^{20}}{4^{20}}$$

For (ii )  , I do as follows :

$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}\times \binom{52}{1}} +\frac{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}\times \binom{52}{1}}$$

Then I subtract the above value from $1$ to get the answer ... Again  ,  if I take $1$ from red and other from black,  the condition holds...  Then  , probability  :

$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}\times \binom{52}{1}}+ \frac{\binom{2}{1}\times \binom{2}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}\binom{52}{1}}$$

But both the answers seem to clash. Where is the main logic? Which one is correct?

Comment: For (i) the answer of $1-(\frac{3}{4})^{20}$ is correct if you make the assumption that the shots are all independent.  If we were being pedantic, we would say that there is in fact not enough information to conclude definitively but we can at least know it is somewhere between $\frac{1}{4}$ and $1$.  For (ii) you have this incorrect in any interpretation of the problem.

Comment: @JMoravitz which answer is correct for (ii)  ?

Comment: For (ii), pay attention to the fact that the cards are drawn with replacement.  Your idea of finding the probability that the two cards are both kings of the same color and subtracting that away from $1$ is a good one.  What is the probability the first card is a king?  What is the probability that the second card is a king which happens to be the same color as the first (*given that the first card was a king*)?

Comment: @JMoravitz For first king,  it is $$\frac{\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}$$

Comment: Yes (*though I would have written it more simply as $\frac{4}{52}$, avoiding the combination notation since it is unnecessary for this problem*)

Comment: For second to be same colour,  it is -$$\frac{\binom{2}{1}}{\binom{52}{1}}$$

Comment: And by multiplying those you correctly get the probability that the two cards are both kings and both the same color to be $\frac{4\times 2}{52\times 52}$ (*which is not equal to your earlier attempt*)

Comment: the probability of getting two kings with replacement is $4/52 \cdot 4/52$. Now there are 4 different color combinations and only two of them satisfy your condition so...

Comment: @JMoravitz...  So you are telling that none of the solutions of (ii) in question is correct?

Comment: You only gave *one* attempted solution in (ii) in your post and that one solution is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @JMoravitz What does subtracting from $1$ take into account,  other than king of different colours (*as the solution is wrong*) ?

Comment: $Pr(\text{not}~A) = 1 - Pr(A)$.  The probability $\frac{4\times 2}{52\times 52}$ is the probability that both cards are kings and they are both the same color.  $1-\frac{4\times 2}{52\times 52}$ is the probability that at least one of the cards is not a king or the cards are different colors, i.e. the probability of not getting kings of same color.

Comment: @JMoravitz...  Not your solution,  but mine,  in the question...

Comment: I don't understand your question then...  The probability $\frac{2\times 2}{\binom{52}{2}}\times \frac{2\times 2}{\binom{52}{2}}$ as well as $1-\frac{2\times 2}{\binom{52}{2}}\times \frac{2\times 2}{\binom{52}{2}}$ are both meaningless in the current context.  A problem that might have made sense that the expression not being subtracted away from $1$ is the probability for would be "You have two shuffled standard 52-card decks of playing cards and you draw two cards from each without replacement.  Find probability that in each draw you get two differently colored kings."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reasoning for (i) is ok.

For (ii):

There are $|\Omega|=52^2=2704$ total possibilities of drawing two cards from the deck with replacement. So there are two ways of not getting the king of the same color:

1. As a first card draw non-king, then the second one could be any card
   $$|A|=\binom{48}{1}\binom{52}{1}=2496$$
2. As a first card draw a king, then the other card shoud not be a king with the same colour:
   $$|B|=\binom{4}{1}\binom{50}{1}=200$$

Of course $A\cap B = \emptyset$, so
$$P=\frac{|A|+|B|}{|\Omega|}=\frac{2696}{2704}\approx .997$$

Comment: Thanks,  that's another way round to tackle the question...